# Slow showmount and NFS mount on AIX

Tags: networking, nfs, aix

```
1:root@GOODSERVER:/root # time showmount -e foo.bar.com > /dev/null 2>&1

real    0m0.01s
user    0m0.00s
sys 0m0.00s
1:root@GOODSERVER:/root # 

vs.: 

4:root@BADSERVER:/root # time showmount -e foo.bar.com > /dev/null 2>&1

real    1m15.04s
user    0m0.00s
sys 0m0.00s
4:root@BADSERVER:/root #
```

"rpcinfo -p" looks ok on BADSERVER and GOODSERVER.

Also NFS mount is slow on the BADSERVER.

When "rpcinfo -p" finishes on the BADSERVER, it shows the output correctly.

**Question**: What network (?) issue could this be? AIX 7.

When I am running showmount with truss

```
_enrecvfrom(20, 0x200263B0, 400, 0, 0x2FF20598, 0x2FF20570, 0x00000000) = 28
```

It seems it doesn't gets this "enrecvfrom" - compared to the GOODSERVER.

It can resolv the domain name and we tried with only IP too.

UPDATE: DNS server is pingable and resolves domains via "dig foo.bar @DNSSERVERIP"

Comment: hard to guess, but it smells like name resolution timeouts; do you have an unreachable DNS server in the mix?

Comment: even if we use only IP? is NFS that bad? :)

Comment: There could be many reasons, depending on your network. Incorrect defined routes, incorrect configured spanning tree atm. If possible try some network monitoring (wireshark, tcpdump, ...) when issuing `showmount` to see what's going on (packages lost, different routes, ..)

Comment: Test the DNS Reverse Lookup on host foo.bar.com, ```host 10.9.8.7``` should show the FQDN of your bad host. And ```host badhost.example.com``` must solve to the right IP address again. (replace 10.9.8.7 and badhost.example.com with your corresponding data)

Comment: As @ingopingo states, it's likely the server at `foo.bar.com` that's having problems doing reverse DNS lookups of the IP address of the request from your badly-performing server.  `foo.bar.com` could be configured to log requests by FQDN, for example, and your badly-performing server can't be found by reverse DNS lookup of its IP.  In other words, the problem is on `foo.bar.com`.

Comment: Maybe ```/etc/nsswitch.conf``` is set up to look for hosts on (dead) NIS servers?  I had yesterday  a similar problem with NFS. In my case it was hanging when getting netgroups (which are not exported by my NIS). Interestingly the long timeout only occurred when nscd was running.